# DL4J UnsatisfiedLinkError: libopenblas_nolapack.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: maven, opencv, deeplearning4j, openblas, dl4j

I tried to set up a deeplearning4j and OpenCV project on Linux via maven, but I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
2020-01-10 16:01:58.239 ERROR 13191 --- [io-13029-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopenblas_nolapack in java.library.path] with root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/.javacpp/cache/openblas-0.3.7-1.5.2-linux-x86_64.jar/org/bytedeco/openblas/linux-x86_64/libjniopenblas_nolapack.so: libopenblas_nolapack.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1493) ~[javacpp-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1192) ~[javacpp-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1042) ~[javacpp-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at org.bytedeco.openblas.global.openblas_nolapack.<clinit>(openblas_nolapack.java:10) ~[openblas-0.3.7-1.5.2.jar!/:0.3.7-1.5.2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1109) ~[javacpp-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1058) ~[javacpp-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter.<clinit>(OpenCVFrameConverter.java:43) ~[javacv-1.5.2.jar!/:1.5.2]
    at org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader.<init>(NativeImageLoader.java:62) ~[datavec-data-image-1.0.0-beta6.jar!/:na]
    at com.lianjia.spider.util.ImageUtils.<clinit>(ImageUtils.java:39) ~[classes!/:1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.lianjia.spider.serivce.impl.captcha.ImageCaptchaServiceImpl.verifyCaptcha(ImageCaptchaServiceImpl.java:28) ~[classes!/:1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.lianjia.spider.controller.CaptchaController.getImageCaptchaVerify(CaptchaController.java:42) ~[classes!/:1.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

My dependencies look like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
        <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-modelimport</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I find a solution from this page: [deeplearning4j](https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/archives/2018/10/04)

Then I do this command from it: `cd /root/.javacpp/cache/openblas-0.3.7-1.5.2-linux-x86_64.jar/org/bytedeco/openblas/linux-x86_64; cp libopenblas.so.0 libopenblas_nolapack.so.0`

It's work,look likes a jar package error.But I want to find a standard solution like change dependency or use maven build to solve it, rather than file operation ,how can i do it?

I find in dependency `openblas` pom,it has a build plugin

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>javacpp-${javacpp.platform}</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>org/bytedeco/openblas/${javacpp.platform}/*mkl*</exclude>
                <exclude>org/bytedeco/openblas/${javacpp.platform}/*omp*</exclude>
                <exclude>org/bytedeco/openblas/${javacpp.platform}/*libopenblas_nolapack*</exclude>
                <exclude>org/bytedeco/openblas/${javacpp.platform}/bin/*openblas*</exclude>
                <exclude>org/bytedeco/openblas/${javacpp.platform}/lib/*libopenblas*</exclude>
                <exclude>${javacpp.platform.library.path}/*libopenblas_nolapack*</exclude>
                <exclude>${javacpp.platform.library.path}/lib/*openblas*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I can see that `libopenblas_nolapack` has been excluded in `<exclude>org/bytedeco/openblas/${javacpp.platform}/*libopenblas_nolapack*</exclude>`,so is it this problem?

Comment: That's usually caused by old versions of Spring: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues/6132

Comment: @SamuelAudet , I update my spring boot version to 2.1.9.R, it works well, thank you ever so much!!